# How do I save every option of a select box in an array? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

Let's say I have an select box: `<select name="cart[]" id="cart" size="5"></select>`

This box is filled with 5 different options.
If I write `$data = $_POST['cart'];` it will only save the option, which is currently selected. How can I save every option (so the ones which are not selected as well)?

Comment: if you want more than one value then you have to allow multiple values with `multiple` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Use the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Advanced_select_with_multiple_features) attribute.

Comment: FYI you can not send unselected values because it does not make sense. If you need them you load it in your post script.

Comment: @daremachine how can I load the ones which are not selected? This is my problem.

Comment: you need to know which values can be sent. Backend should validate them so if you have generic option values created from php loop in html then you need same load in backend. If you not have any, then i dont understand what you want and think your design is very bad.

Comment: That literally defeats the purpose of a select box. Why do you need all the values and how do you intend to differentiate which was selected and what was not?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the unselected value from `$_POST`, but you can do as follows

```
$allOption = [
    1,2,3,4,5
];
$selected = $_POST['cart'];
$unselected = array_diff($allOption, $selected);
```